# Why is strlen conting the null character here?

Tags: c, printf, c-strings, fgets, strlen

Normaly `strlen` does not count the null terminator at the end of the string. But the  below code prints the string count with the null terminator. Can anyone explain me why?

```
int main(){
    char name[100];
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
    printf("length is : %d", strlen(name));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't count the null character, it counts the trailing `\n`. Try `printf("<%s>", name);` and see what happens. Also read the documentation of [`fgets`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) closely. Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Answer (score 1):

The function `fgets` can append to the entered string the new line character `'\n'`. So the function `strlen` counts this new line character.

From the C Standard (7.21.7.2 The fgets function)

> 2 The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of
> characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into
> the array pointed to by s. No additional characters are read after a
> new-line character (**which is retained**) or after end-of-file. A
> null character is written immediately after the last character read
> into the array.

To remove the new line character from the string you can write

```
name[ strcspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

After that you can call the function `printf` using the conversion specifier `zu` instead of `d` (otherwise the call has undefined behavior).

```
printf("length is : %zu\n", strlen(name));
```

Comment: Or, to remove the newline character, you can use: ```name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';```

Comment: @Filippo It is an unsafe approach. It is not necessary that the string will contain the new line character.